# WordPress Theme Updating Post

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, custom-post-type

I am using a Wordpress theme (autotrader) which has a customer post type 'vehicle'. I am importing my vehicles with WP All Import and that works perfectly. However my vehicles don't appear in the search results when using the front end. Basically this is because the theme includes an additional database table (tf_autotrader_seek_index_posts) to store the search data.

If I open one of the imported vehicles in the admin and press "update" it will create the required record in this table for me. However with over 250 vehicles and more being imported every day it's impractical to go into the admin, open each vehicle and press update. I was hoping I could write a loop such as this to update every customer post type ...

```
$args = array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_type' => 'vehicle'
);

$my_posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ) {
wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
```

This runs fine but it doesn't create the required records in the tf_autotrader_seek_index_posts table. I can therefore only assume that the theme runs some extra code when updating a vehicle form the wp-admin that isn't being run when I run wp_update_post from my script.

Any ideas on how I even find out what the theme is doing when it updates a vehicle so I can replicate the functionality from my script?

Many Thanks

Comment: All assumptions without being able to see the code, but there is likely an action hook somewhere that is updating the search index. My guess would be `save_post` but that should =have been covered by your code (though I would write it differently). Check your theme to see what is writing to `tf_autotrader_seek_index_posts` and work your way back from there, post relevant code if you still need help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes that's what I'm doing trying to work backwards through the themes code. Sadly there code is quite long winded and fairly messy. I would have thought calling wp_update_post( $my_post ); would call any theme specific hooks is that not the case?

Comment: It was a good guess, but I'm not sure without seeing all the code in your theme. Good luck!